# Tomcat 6 connection pool goes wacky when CMS GC is used

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling, tomcat6

We recently changed to the CMS garbage collector on our server (`XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`) which worked fine in tests. When we went to production, things were OK for the first few hours, but then we suddenly began to see the dreaded:

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection,
pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
```

We have seen these messages when the database is physically down or heavily loaded, but this wasn't the case this time. So I began wondering if the recent GC change might be the culprit.

What I don't understand is why we haven't seen this before. Would the change of GC to concurrent-mark-sweep change something (finalizers, perhaps) that would expose problems with this configuration?

My `context.xml` params look something like this:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/DB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="64" maxIdle="60" maxWait="10000"
            defaultAutoCommit="false"
```

I read [this link](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/04/01/configuring-jdbc-pool-high-concurrency) and began wondering if these were incredibly naive parameters. From my understanding, above 60 connections we will start opening and closing connections without returning them to the pool. But I don't still understand if there is a connection between this and our GC change.

We're using Tomcat 6.0.29 with the MySQL 5.1.45 (5.1.12 JDBC connector).

Answer (score 2):

use `removeAbandoned="true"` when you are initializing your connection-pool.
Follow the this link http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

60 connections is way to much. What kind of application do you run?

In any case I highly suggest moving away from dbcp and using something like http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/